# Get nested array depends on a dropdown selection and make it observable

Tags: knockout.js

I'm stuck with implement following:

[Feature I need to implement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ticmp.png)

The logic is following: depends on user selected form, get all sections related to this form. E.g: If user selects form with name "T-01", then sections array must be populated with all sections related to this form. And each Section must be observable for further calculation.

Here is my Form model:

```
function Form(name, title, max, total, sections) {
  this.Name = ko.observable(name);
  this.Title = ko.observable(title);
  this.MAX = ko.observable(max);
  this.Total = ko.observable(total);
  this.Sections = ko.observableArray(sections);
  this.addSection = function () {
    this.Sections.push(new Section());
  }.bind(this);
}

var FormOptions = ko.observableArray(['T-01', 'T-02', 'T-03']);
```

And here the Section model:

```
function Section(section, criteria, is, cs, nc, fc, totalInitialScores, totalFinalScores) {
  this.Section = ko.observable(section);
  this.Criteria = ko.observable(criteria);
  this.IS = ko.observable(is);
  this.CS = ko.observable(cs);
  this.NC = ko.observable(nc);
  this.FC = ko.observable(fc);
  this.TotalInitialScores = ko.observable(totalInitialScores);
  this.TotalFinalScores = ko.observable(totalFinalScores);
}
```

I have few models on a root level, but I don't include it here, not sure if it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ko.pureComputed` or `ko.computed` properties to create dynamic selections of data.

As far as I can tell from the code you've shown (unfortunately, not a working snippet...), there are two observable collections:

- An observable array of `Name` strings
- An observable array of `Form` view models that have a similar `Name` property

You can use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to create a new array of forms like so:

```
const selectedForms = allForms.filter(f => selectedNames.includes(f.name));
```

Which, in plain English, says: "Return to me a list of forms which have a name that appears in my list of selected names".

Now, if we wrap this code in a computed and create dependencies to all observable properties, you get:

```
var selectedForms = ko.pureComputed(function() {
  return allForms().filter(function(form) {
   return FormOptions().includes(form.Name());
  });
});
```

This computed updates whenever its needed and one of its dependencies updates.So, when you add/remove a form from `allForms`, when a `Name` property changes or when `FormOptions` change.

Now that you have a list of selected forms, you can create a second computed: a list of sections. This is a concatenation of the sections of your selected forms:

```
var selectedFormsSections = ko.pureComputed(function() {
  return selectedForms().reduce(function(allSections, form) {
    return allSections.concat(form.Sections());
  }, []);
});
```

This array updates when either the selected forms change, or when a section is added/removed to/from one of these forms.